# Etymology of circumfix present continuous (a-fly-ing)

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the story behind “a-” prefix / suffix?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix)

I'm writing an introductory lecture on morphology and as a familiar example of circumfixes I found (on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumfix), but it's since been removed it seems) the *a-fly-ing* form of the present continuous from older English, which is nice and familiar.

But I got to thinking: Where does that *a* come from? My other familiar example, the German perfect participle (*ge-spiel-t*), I know (a derivational prefix in common Germanic). But the *a-* in the present continuous, I have no clue. Does anyone know where this comes from?

Comment: OP: Do you think the question is substantially different from or adds to the one cited by @tenfour?

Comment: Nope, pretty much the same question. I just didn't find it before posting my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this version of the **a-** prefix (*a-flying, a-hunting,* etc.) is the same as *aglow*, for example, where it means *in the process of, in a particular state*. I wouldn't call it a circumfix at all - it's just that in those first two words there's also a suffix **-ing** (again, indicating a continuous state).

I think there are at least a dozen different **a-** prefixes in English, but this particular one seems to me to be either the same or closely related to the one in *aside, aback,* etc., where it means *to, towards*. [etymonline(1)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-&allowed_in_frame=0) says...

> **a- (1)** in native (derived from O.E.) words, most commonly represents O.E. *an* "on" (see a (2)), as in *alive, asleep, abroad, afoot*, etc., forming adjectives and adverbs from nouns; but it also can be M.E. *of*, as in *anew, abreast* (1590s); or a reduced form of O.E. pp. prefix *ge-*, as in *aware*; or the O.E. intens. *a-*, as in *arise, awake, ashame*, marking a verb as momentary, a single event.
>
> **a- (2)** prefix meaning "not," from L. *a-*, short for *ab* "away from" (cf. *avert*), or its cognate, Gk. *a-*, short for *apo* "away from, from," both cognate with Skt. *apa* "away from," Goth. *af*, O.E. *of*.

EDIT: The question of what exactly constitutes a *"circumfix"* in English is tricky, to say the least. I used to think **y---t** in now-archaic [yclept](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yclept) (from also-archaic *clepe* "to name, call, dub, entitle") was about the only example. But [here are guys in Wikipedia 'talk'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Circumfix) arguing for **em---en** *(embolden)*, and **be---ed** *(beloved)*. So maybe **a---ing** qualifies after all.

Comment: +1 because the first part of your reference is relevant and constitutes a good answer. But I believe that the second meaning of the prefix **a-** is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Irene: You mean the etymonline section **a- (2)**? I only put that in at the last minute because their **a- (1)** text referenced it (I didn't include the totally irrelevant **a- (3)** section about Gk *a-, an-* "not"). Or are you saying you think the **a** in *aback, aside* has no etymological connection to *a-flying, aglow*? I'm only guessing on that one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In the question tenfour found you suggest it might also ultimately be Germ. _ga-_ perfectiveser as in the German past participle, but I suppose that'd be an odd combination with present continuous, which is essentially an imperfective form of the verb. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @arnsholt: I'm no historical linguist (or even *linguist ordinaire*, come to that), so these really *are* only "thoughts". But it seems to me *a-wassailing*, for example, is essentially a gerund. So I'd go for "O.E. intens. *a-*" above, coupled with [Wikipedia's Etymology 1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Etymology_1) saying the end part is "Middle English *-ing* from Old English *-ing*, *-ung* from Proto-Germanic *-ungō*."

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Of course I am referring to the etymonline section **a-(2)**.