# What is the difference between the adjectives "live" and "alive"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, connotation

What is the difference between "live" and "alive"? When would I better use the first and when the latter?

---

Say, there are several players actively participating in a game and some others are waiting on the bench. I used to call those "active" players "live players". Although there may be other valid phrases for that I believe this one should be ok as well (right?).

But I am unsure if "live" works with questions: can I ask "Is this player live" or should it be "Is this player alive"? The first one sounds awkward to me, but the latter sounds to me as if I was asking whether he's dead and not only whether he's out of the game.

Comment: Do the examples in a dictionary help? Eg, see ODO on [live](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/live--2) and [alive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alive). If not, please edit the question to say what the problem is.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is that both words have several meanings. For some of those meanings the words may be interchangeable, or close, for others not.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think "alive" is used only whenever that's opposed to "dead", while "live" may be opposed by "inanimate", "artificial", "pre-recorded" and all other variations. There were live/alive worms in your food? Did you expect dead worms in your food? If not, they were live, not alive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the story behind "a-" prefix / suffix?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix). Essentially, prefixing [verb] with *a-* implies *actively continuing to perform [verb]*. Something which is *alive* is actively so, as opposed to simply being *live* rather than *dead*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as if you are trying to convey a binary status such as *active* and *inactive*.  This is one of the many meanings of [live](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live)

> 2.: exerting force or containing energy: as
>   a : afire, glowing *live coals*
>   b : connected to electric power
>   c : charged with explosives and containing shot or a bullet *live ammunition*;
>    also : armed but not exploded *a live bomb*
>   d : imparting or driven by power *a live axle*
>   e : being in operation *a live microphone*

Each of these uses suggest the ability to turn the status on or off. This is a common usage in American English.

It is true that *[alive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alive)* can also convey active status

> 2 . a : still in existence, force, or operation : active *kept hope alive*
>   b : still active in competition with a chance of victory *must win to stay alive in the playoffs*

However, this usage is not common where there is little direct control over the *alive* status. One would not say *an alive circuit* or *alive ammunition*. In fact, *alive* is more often used as a predicate adjective than an ordinary modifier.

> The passengers were *alive*!

Comment: +1 predecate adjective

Answer (score 14):

Generally, *live* is an attributive adjective, and *alive* is used as a predicate adjective; in other words, *live* is usually placed directly before the noun, and *alive* is generally not.

> These are *live* goldfish.
> These goldfish are *alive*.

*Lexico's* definition of [live](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/live) (adjective sense 1) and [alive](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alive) (sense 1) are "not dead or inanimate; living" and "*[predicative]* living, not dead".

There are several other differences in shades of meaning, some of which you can figure out by looking at the rest of the definitions, but this is the main difference. There are also exceptions to this rule; for example, if you are talking about real-time broadcasting, electrical wires, or ammunition, you always use *live,* even in predicate position.

> This is *live* television.
> Watch what you say; this television broadcast is *live*.
> *Live* from New York, it's Saturday Night!

Comment: Let's remember the old-time poster with the outlaw's photo: Wanted / Dead or Alive, and *Molly Malone*:' Crying, "Cockles and mussels, alive, alive, oh!"'