# What's the grammar of the song title "Baby I'm-a Want You"?

Tags: contractions

There is a famous song called [Baby I'm-a Want You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_I%27m-a_Want_You_(song)).

The name sounds wrong. Why is it not "Baby I want you"? Auxiliary verb "am" and article "a" look excessive  in this phrase.

Comment: Hello, Mia. Song lyrics are often off-topic on ELU as they depart so significantly from standard usages (to fit with the music, usually). I'm afraid this is the case here. (Later in the song, 'Maybe I'm-a crazy' sounds like a mangling by Chico Marx in his Italianate parody. But 'Lately, I'm-a prayin' does make use of the archaic 'a-Ving', as in 'a-wassailing',  covered on ELU at [What is the grammatical basis for using "a" before a present participle (-ing)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300011/what-is-the-grammatical-basis-for-using-a-before-a-present-participle-ing) etc).

Answer (score 2):

It represents the conversational pronunciation of

> I am going to want you.

[OXfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=I%27m%20a%20meaning&ei=ev7JZOygLa24hbIPxtiuoAo&ved=0ahUKEwjsxbH6sr2AAxUtXEEAHUasC6QQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=I%27m%20a%20meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiDUknbSBhIG1lYW5pbmcyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHkjjElAAWIELcAB4AZABAJgB5AGgAcQIqgEDMi01uAEDyAEA-AEBwgIIEAAYigUYkQLCAgcQABiKBRhDwgIFEAAYgATiAwQYACBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) says about ***I'ma*** (also spelt **Ima**)

> contraction INFORMAL •US
> verb: Ima
> I'm going to.
>
> - I guess ***I'ma*** just wing it.

[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/gonna-and-wanna-1212038) explains:

> ***Wanna*** and ***gonna*** are examples of ***reductions***. Reductions are short, commonly used phrases that are spoken quickly.

You can say the same about ***I'm a want you***. ***am going to*** is reduced to ***'m a***.
[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Imma) defines ***Imma*** as

> Written form of a **relaxed pronunciation** of ***I'm gonna***.

and gives a list of alternatives:

> I'mma, imma, I'ma, i'ma, Ima, ima, Ima', I'm a, I'm a', i'm a', I'm'a, i'm'a, I'm-a.

Comment: It seems a non-standard use of "I'm going to".

Comment: You might change "the" to "a". Oxford's  INFORMAL-US is something like saying INFORMAL-UK if the pronunciation were limited to areas of Scotland.

Comment: This pronunciation is hardly comparable to "gonna", which extends across virtually all social, economic, age-group, and educational strata.

Comment: Urban Dictionary gives this definition to *imma* https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imma