# What is the function of 'a-' in the phrase 'cocks a-crow'

Tags: meaning, word-formation

This is a beginning of W.B.Yeats's poem **Under Ben Bulben**:

> Swear by what the Sages spoke
>   Round the Mareotic Lake
>   That the Witch of Atlas knew,
>   Spoke and set the cocks a-crow.

What is the function of **a-** in the phrase **cocks a-crow**? What is the general structure and meaning?
I think this function is different from what explained in this [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix)

I guess here **a-** applied in the meaning of **of**. The Oxford dictionary indicates this meaning and brings the example of **anew**.

Comment: Give us more context, please. Also a link to the source would be helpful, including information about when it was written.

Comment: It _is_ the same as 'a-carolling' as in the link, meaning that they were doing the action specified.

Comment: The 'duplicate' answer deals with *a-(verb)-ing* pretty well; and a brief answer from *Barrie England* mentions six categories of **a-** in the OED (which we can't afford), but this is quite different.  It obviously doesn't belong with *aloft, athwart, astern,* but perhaps with *"abed"* which is not so rare.

Comment: And possibly *"asleep"*

Comment: Ok. So can you tell me who is the subject of the last line. Who set the crows? Sages?

Comment: From the OED:  "2. With nouns and verb stems, forming adverbs (and derived adjectives and prepositions) expressing activity, position, condition, etc. Now chiefly poetic." One of their citations (Robert Browning): *The other man, a-grime With guilt.*