# meaning of prefix "a"

Tags: prefixes

While searching for an alternative synonym for the adjective ***starving***, I found the word ***ahungered*** and I was intrigued by the use of the prefix ***a*** in this case.

I looked up the etymology of [the prefix ***a-***](https://www.etymonline.com/word/a-#:%7E:text=a%2D%20(3),asexual%2C%20amoral%2C%20agnostic.) .

Edit: While I am aware that there are similar questions concerning this prefix, I would need an explanation for this particular word:

When I first came across [***ahungered***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ahungered#:%7E:text=archaic,%3A%20made%20hungry%20%3A%20very%20hungry), I intuitively thought that here ***a-*** implies that the noun it describes was ***made hungry***, as opposed to simply *getting hungry*. Is this intuition correct? Can the prefix acquire a grammatical meaning, if I can use this expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the story behind "a-" prefix / suffix?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix) [in examples like _If this van's a-rockin', don't come a-knockin'_ and 
_Here We Come A-caroling_ {a-wassailing}]. //// 'I think it often denotes some kind of "continuing activity or state" (asleep, abed, astir), so there's an element of tautology when used with -ing forms such as a-wassailing.' – FumbleFingers Oct 21 '11

Comment: *I looked up the etymology of the prefix a- .* If you have done this, you will have seen: **It also can represent Middle English of (prep.) "off, from," as in anew, afresh, akin, abreast. Or it can be a reduced form of the Old English past participle prefix ge-, as in aware.** Either way, it is not a word that you will use.

Comment: @Greybeard: I am actually using it in the translation of an ancient text. Yes, I did see that definition but it is not clear to me how "ahungered" can mean "off, from hunger". I had also found that it can refer to a momentary event, but EdA seems to indicate that it is rather a "continuing activity". My main question is however if a prefix can change the "grammatical connotation" of a verb.