# Verb tense in Phineas and Ferb song “History of Rock”

Tags: tenses, conditionals

I've been learning English for decades but I still don't get how its verb tenses work.

The *Phineas and Ferb* episode “Dude, We're Getting the Band Back Together” has the song “History of Rock”.  In its second verse, Danny recounts how he started to play music.

> Danny: I asked my daddy for a guitar, ah, I begged and I plead,
> I said I wanted to play the blues, and he just nodded his head.
> Daddy said when he was my age,  "Boogie-Woogie" was the thing...
> Phineas: Just take the blues, throw out your hip, and add a little swing...
> Danny: Ah, music has the power, that without it, he'd a-sworn
> that he'd a never met my mom and I'd a-never been born...

Please explain why the lyrics say “he'd a never met my mom”.  Does it stand for “he would have never met my mom”?  How does that make sense in context?  When did or would have Danny's dad swear?

Comment: Related (at least for some of this): [What is the story behind "a-" prefix / suffix?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45886/191178).

Comment: When you say: He'd a never met my mom, that means in this case: He would never have met my mom. This is not a- prefix....This kind of thing is also expressed as: He'd never a met my mom. a=have here. Southern speech or unschooled speech. Also, he'd a sworn is: He would have sworn. All those a's are the verb have which can become a in fast speech.

Comment: Shoulda, woulda, coulda.